# If all of the component functions of a space curve $\gamma$ are quadratic, then the image of $\gamma$ lies in a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I'm trying to prove that if all three component functions of a space curve $\gamma$ are quadratic functions, then the image of $\gamma$ is contained in a plane. I know that $\gamma(t)$ is contained in a plane iff the image of $\gamma(t)-\textbf{k}$ is contained in a plane for some constant vector $\textbf{k}$. So if I write $\gamma(t)=(a_1t^2+b_1t+c_1, a_2t^2+b_2t+c_2, a_3t^2++b_3t+c_3)$ and take $\textbf{k}=\gamma(0)=(c_1, c_2, c_3)$, I then need to show that the three polynomials that are the coordinates of $\gamma(t)-\textbf{k}$ are linearly dependent. I have $x=(a_1t^2+b_2t), y=(a_2t^2+b_2t), \text{ and } z=(a_3t^2+b_3t)$, but I'm not sure how to show that these are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space of all quadratic functions whose constant term is $0$ is $2$-dimensional; it has the polynomial functions $x$ and $x^2$ as a basis. So, since you have three of them, they are linearly dependent.